# Simple_form styling(Remove borders and text alignment center)

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, forms, simple-form, simple-form-for

I am trying to have have my TODO list be able to be dynamically edited on the same page. My idea was to use simple_form to display the information and hide the borders. I need the text displayed to be centralized. However, I am having difficulties with the styling as nothing is shown. I would like to know if this is possible? Or is there a better way to make my TODO be able to be edited without going to another page form.

```
<div class = "border_show">
     <%= simple_form_for @item do |f| %>
       <%= f.input :title, label: false, required: true, :class => "form_border" %>
       <%= f.input :description, label: false %>
       <%= f.input :category, label: false %>
       <%= f.button :submit, 'submit', :style => "display: none;" %>
     <% end %>

     <%= link_to "Back", root_path %>
     <%= link_to "Delete", item_path(@item), method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"} %>
</div>
```

**border_show** is to create a border for styling:

```
.border_show{
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    font-family: Bookman, URW;
    color: black;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.701);
    width: 50%;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-radius: 25px;
}  

.form_border{
    border-style: none;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I tried to replace class for **form_border** to **id** but it did not work too.

Image of how my form looks now:
[image: image of how my form looks now]

Answer (score 0):

If it's css issue then, I have edited your css name form-border to form_border class.

```
.form_border{
   border-style: none;
   text-align: center;
}
```

If it's still doesn't work then add:

```
.form_border{
   border-style: none !important;
   text-align: center;
}
```

If it still doesn't work, you can ping me.

Comment: I tried but it didn't work. I updated how it currently looks now.

Comment: I switched to form_for and it works but simple_form doesn't seem to work.